# How to get which route called a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-route-dom, I want to implement this config:

```
<Route exact path='/test/:id' component={MyComponent}/>
<Route exact path='/test2/:id' component={MyComponent}/>
```

then in MyComponent, I want to make something different depending on which route is calling it.

```
const MyComponent = ({info: {param}, info2: {param1, param2}}) => {


  return (
    <div>

    </div>

  )
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  info: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  info2: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  info: state.info,
  info2: state.info2
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(MyComponent);
```

How can I get the test or test2 params?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the entire path using props.location

Answer (score 0):

You can send it via props:

```
<Route exact path='/test/:id'>
  <MyComponent route={'test'} />
</Route>
```

Comment: this works, how can I get the route props in a component using hooks?

Comment: Why would you use hooks? Just use props.

Comment: I mean I am using a function component connected to redux

Comment: I changed a bit the question to better show what I am trying to do

Comment: const MyComponent = ({info: {param}, info2: {param1, param2}, route})

Comment: You're overriding props here: `const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  ...props,
  info: state.info,
  info2: state.info2
});`